# Instruction timings and operand values

Tags: assembly, intel, amd-processor

With a quick glance through Intel's software developer manuals, I couldn't find any clear information on whether or not the timings of any instructions depend on the value of the given operands. If there are instructions that have this property, are they documented somewhere in one place? CPUs of the late 90s used to have this property (which was the last time I wrote any larger pieces of assembly code).

(I'm interested in this information for both Intel and AMD CPUs)

Comment: [Agner Fog's manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf) contain a lot of useful information, including which instructions have variable latency on various x86's.

Comment: Unfortunately denormalized floating-point values as still dog-slow on common x86/64 processors, at least the vectorized versions. Hence the control bits to treat them as zeroes.

Comment: The setting for this is implementing encryption algorithms (Qui dropped the tag, although it's quite relevant here), so mostly bit shifts, rotations, integer arithmetic. I'm not really looking into things that are out of control of the programmer, say, caused by paging. Although, any data manipulated would of course be allocated within the same page to reduce side channel attacks caused by paging issues.

Comment: BTW, who's the smart guy downvoting answers? He doesn't seem to want to elaborate on his reasons.

Comment: Division and square root. Obviously also string instructions, which do a variable amount of work.

Comment: @EOF: Agner Fog's manuals look really good. Intel's manuals seem to have become really bloated. It looks like the marketing team has done a pass over them adding lots of BS with zero information content.